# For loop to paste rows to create new dataframe from existing dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, concatenation

New to SO, but can't figure out how to get this code to work. I have a dataframe that is very large, and is set up like this:

```
Number    Year    Type    Amount
1         1       A       5
1         2       A       2
1         3       A       7
1         4       A       1
1         1       B       5
1         2       B       11
1         3       B       0
1         4       B       2
```

This goes onto multiple for multiple numbers. I want to take this dataframe and make a new dataframe that has two of the rows together, but it would be nested (for example, row 1 and row 2, row 1 and row 3, row 1 and row 4, row 2 and row 3, row 2 and row 4) where each combination of each year is together within types and numbers.

Example output:

```
Number    Year    Type    Amount   Number    Year    Type    Amount
1         1       A       5         1          2       A       2
1         1       A       5         1          3       A       7
1         1       A       5         1          4       A       1
1         2       A       2         1          3       A       7
1         2       A       2         1          4       A       1
1         3       A       7         1          4       A       1
```

I thought that I would do a for loop to loop within number and type, but I do not know how to make the rows paste from there, or how to ensure that I am only getting the combinations of the rows once. For example:

```
for(i in 1:n_number){
for(j in 1:n_type){
....}}
```

Any tips would be appreciated! I am relatively new to coding, so I don't know if I should be using a for loop at all. Thank you!

Comment: I _think_ this is for a scala dataframe. If I'm wrong, please retag. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Edit: I have added an example of the final table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Number= rep(1,8),
                 Year = rep(c(1:4),2),
                 Type = rep(c('A','B'),each=4),
                 Amount=c(5,2,7,1,5,11,0,2))
```

My interpretation is that you want to create a dataframe with all row combinations, where `Number` and `Type` are the same and `Year` is different.

First suggestion - join on `Number` and `Type`, then remove rows that have different `Year`. I added an index to prevent redundant matches (1 with 2 and 2 with 1).

```
df$index <- 1:nrow(df)
out <- merge(df,df,by=c("Number","Type"))
out <- out[which(out$index.x>out$index.y & out$Year.x!=out$Year.y),]
```

Second suggestion - if you want to see a version using a loop.

```
out2 <- NULL
for (i in c(1:(nrow(df)-1))){
  for (j in c((i+1):nrow(df))){
    if(df[i,"Year"]!=df[j,"Year"] & df[i,"Number"]==df[j,"Number"]  & df[i,"Type"]==df[j,"Type"]){
      out2 <- rbind(out2,cbind(df[i,],df[j,]))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to do this within 'Number' and 'Type' only, would I add that in at the beginning? I want to create the combinations of year for each type by itself, within each number grouping.

Comment: @A.Spence - I see that I had misinterpreted in my original answer. Let me know if the edit above isn't correct.